# How can I change segments after I created an object?

Tags: modeling, interface

I have started to learn blender. I have a problem with re-changing segments. When I create an object, object panel gives options at left bar but if I close that panel; I couldn't reach it again. I have already searched and found "no, you cannot" answer. But Is there any additional solution? I have used F6 button, it just gives transform panel only.

[image]

Comment: F6 pops up the last operator used.  If translate is popping up via F6 implies you have translated the object after adding it.

Comment: Once the original object has been created, and has gone through some kind of transformation, there is no way to get the original creation parameters panel back